# Improvement on 3 Criteria Vlookup macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have a list with 3 variables in the sheet "Combined" in columns A; B; C.

The workbook contains 98 sheets, with those 3 variables still in A; B; C columns but in different combinations and with a fourth column which never repeats itself, as the sheets go on, which i need to bring in the "Combined" sheet, always adding another column for the next sheet I vlookup. : A B C + D(from the next sheet) + E(from the next sheet) and so on.

I have a UDF that Vlookups on 3 based on 3 criterias and a macro that cycles through the sheets and bring the values where i want them. The problem is, it's pretty slow, left it from yesterday and its on sheet 60. Any suggestions on improving it would greatly help, Thank you in advance!

```
Function ThreeVlookup(Table_Range As Range, Return_Col As Long, Col1_Fnd, Col2_Fnd, Col3_Fnd)
Dim rCheck As Range, bFound As Boolean, lLoop As Long
On Error Resume Next
Set rCheck = Table_Range.Columns(1).Cells(1, 1)
With WorksheetFunction
    For lLoop = 1 To .CountIf(Table_Range.Columns(1), Col1_Fnd)
    Set rCheck = Table_Range.Columns(1).Find(Col1_Fnd, rCheck, xlValues, xlWhole, xlNext, xlRows, False)
        If UCase(rCheck(1, 2)) = UCase(Col2_Fnd) And UCase(rCheck(1, 3)) = UCase(Col3_Fnd) Then
            bFound = True
    Exit For
        End If
    Next lLoop
End With
If bFound = True Then
    ThreeVlookup = rCheck(1, Return_Col)
Else
    ThreeVlookup = ""
End If
End Function

Sub test()
Dim lookupVal1 As Range, lookupVal2 As Range, lookupVal3 As Range, myString As Variant, n&, u As Long
n = Sheets("Combined").[A:A].Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
u = 4
For j = 2 To Worksheets.Count
For i = 1 To n
    Set lookupVal1 = Sheets("Combined").Cells(i, 1)
    Set lookupVal2 = Sheets("Combined").Cells(i, 2)
    Set lookupVal3 = Sheets("Combined").Cells(i, 3)
        myString = ThreeVlookup(Sheets(j).Range("A:D"), 4, lookupVal1, lookupVal2, lookupVal3)
            Sheets("Combined").Cells(i, u) = myString
Next i
u = u + 1
Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: you could go at it another way, combine the values on columns A:C to one string, and have an helper column on every sheet (or an Array), and then you have just 1 Vlookup to compare the `CONCATENATE` array

Answer (score 0):

Use Arrays to speed it up, my friend!  Load all your sheets (or just the current sheet in the loop) into an array in VBA's memory and do the .CountIf and .Find on arrayVar(row) instead of Table_Range.Columns(1).

You will be really surprised how much quicker it goes.  Do it!

Here's a tutorial I like on arrays...

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx

Here's a guy who speed-tested an application like yours...

https://fastexcel.wordpress.com/2011/10/26/match-vs-find-vs-variant-array-vba-performance-shootout/

The basics is like this:

```
Sub Play_With_Arrays()

Dim varArray() As Variant
Dim lngArray() As Long
ReDim varArray(1 To 1000)
ReDim lngArray(1 To 1000)

For A = 1 To 1000
    lngArray(A) = A / 2
    varArray(A) = A / 2 & " examples"
Next

searchterm = 345

For B = 1 To 1000
    If lngArray(B) = searchterm Then
       FoundRow = B
    End If
Next

searchterm2 = "5 ex"
FoundStrRowCount = 0

For C = 1 To 1000
    If InStr(1, varArray(C), searchterm2, vbBinaryCompare) Then
        FoundStrRowCount = FoundStrRowCount + 1
    End If
Next

MsgBox (FoundRow & " in long array and " & FoundStrRowCount & " in var array")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be much faster:

```
Public Function ThreeVLookup(ByVal arg_Col1LookupVal As Variant, _
                             ByVal arg_Col2LookupVal As Variant, _
                             ByVal arg_Col3LookupVal As Variant, _
                             ByVal arg_LookupTable As Range, _
                             ByVal arg_ReturnColumn As Long) _
  As Variant

    Dim rConstants As Range, rFormulas As Range
    Dim rAdjustedTable As Range
    Dim aTable As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    On Error Resume Next
    Set rConstants = arg_LookupTable.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set rFormulas = arg_LookupTable.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Select Case (Not rConstants Is Nothing) + 2 * (Not rFormulas Is Nothing)
        Case 0:     ThreeVLookup = vbNullString
                    Exit Function
        Case -1:    Set rAdjustedTable = rConstants
        Case -2:    Set rAdjustedTable = rFormulas
        Case -3:    Set rAdjustedTable = Union(rConstants, rFormulas)
    End Select

    If WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(rAdjustedTable.Resize(, 1), arg_Col1LookupVal, rAdjustedTable.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 1), arg_Col2LookupVal, rAdjustedTable.Resize(, 1).Offset(, 2), arg_Col3LookupVal) = 0 Then
        ThreeVLookup = vbNullString
        Exit Function
    End If

    aTable = rAdjustedTable.Value

    For i = LBound(aTable, 1) To UBound(aTable, 1)
        If aTable(i, 1) = arg_Col1LookupVal And aTable(i, 2) = arg_Col2LookupVal And aTable(i, 3) = arg_Col3LookupVal Then
            ThreeVLookup = aTable(i, arg_ReturnColumn)
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i

End Function

Sub tgr()

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim wsCombined As Worksheet
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim aResults() As Variant
    Dim aCombined As Variant
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
    Set wsCombined = wb.Sheets("Combined")
    aCombined = wsCombined.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Value
    ReDim aResults(1 To UBound(aCombined, 1) - LBound(aCombined, 1) + 1, 1 To wb.Sheets.Count - 1)

    For i = LBound(aCombined, 1) To UBound(aCombined, 1)
        j = 0
        For Each ws In wb.Sheets
            If ws.Name <> wsCombined.Name Then
                j = j + 1
                aResults(i, j) = ThreeVLookup(aCombined(i, 1), aCombined(i, 2), aCombined(i, 3), ws.Range("A:D"), 4)
            End If
        Next ws
    Next i

    wsCombined.Range("D1").Resize(UBound(aResults, 1), UBound(aResults, 2)).Value = aResults

End Sub
```